# sql-lite take info from rows and paste that to a single colum

Tags: sqlite

Heej,

I have to take the info from '[Plaats**] to a new colum called [OR] (not vissible in image)

[Link to image](http://gyazo.com/d542dea35801aa2287ba9ea110e96e87)

i want in colum [OR]  the text: LO: HASSELT/ ALMELO/ ENSCHEDE/ BERKUM/ EMMELOORD/ GLANERBRUG/ NUNSPEET/ LUTTENBERG/ ENSCHEDE/ MEPPEL/ TWELLO/ HENGELO/

i dont want the name: any place name (like: ALMELO and ENSCHEDE) twice in the result 
so there have to come a rule that blocks double place names.

what i know at this point is:

```
Update bron set [OR] = 'LO: ' || [Plaats**] || '/'
```

at this point in [OR] there will appear the txt: 'LO: HASSELT/'

but now the rest.

Greets Jasper.

Comment: And why is Enschede allowed to appear twice?

Comment: ENSCHEDE is also not allowed sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT 'LO: ' || group_concat(Plaats, '/ ')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Plaats**] AS Plaats
      FROM bron
      -- ORDER BY ...
     )
```

To write this value to all rows, use an UPDATE statement like this:

```
UPDATE bron
SET [OR] = (SELECT 'LO: ' || group_concat(Plaats, '/ ')
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Plaats**] AS Plaats
                  FROM bron
                  -- ORDER BY ...
                 ))
```

Comment: This is not working.Could you pls explaine what it does one by one?

Comment: could you tell me in wich culom the output goes?

Comment: This query returns a single column.

Comment: 'no such function as groupconcat', i use a program called fileconverter and then sql-conversion not query